# Matplotlib produces unwanted tabbed windows for plt

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, anaconda

I simply want to plot two separate plots (i.e. plots in separate windows) using python (anaconda installation) and matplotlib. But when I run the example code below, I get a single window that contains two tabbed windows within it.

```
plt.figure(1)
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.show()

plt.figure(2)
s = 1 + np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Which environment are you running the code in? Which operating system, IDE, etc.? BTW, only one call to plt.show() is needed. It will show all the figures and start the matplotlib event loop.

Comment: I get two separate windows with two graphs ...

Comment: I ran it in Spyder, and I got two separate graphs in two different windows

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am using a Macbook running OS 10.14.4 (Mojave) and I use anaconda3 python. If I run from Spyder, two separate windows appear inside the IDE, but if I then do %matplotlib qt to make them appear outside the IDE, I get this tabbed window. I also get tabs when I run from the terminal using pythonw. The backend for matplotlib is "MacOSX". I have noticed that the "TkAgg" backend that I used to run is now no longer available after a re-installation of anaconda and wonder if this is connected?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code in pycharm and it does exactly as you want. I think the environment you are running it through is causing the issue. Also only use the plt.show() at the end (this may fix it anyway).

You could try using subplots if this doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax1 = plt.plot(t, s)


ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
s = 1 + np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
ax2 = plt.plot(t, s)
plt.show()
```